# Best Way To Reference Current/Working Directory in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am after the one which is most used. A number of ones I have come across are:

- CurDir
- Environment.CurrentDirectory()
- AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
- Application.StartupPath (this one doesn't work for me, missing a library?)

I am using it to save a file, for argument sake, "test.txt"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be oversimplifying, but if you want to save something in the folder where your app is running, just omit the path.

```
call MyObj.SaveTo("test.txt")
```

Comment: Thankyou. Could I call this and reference a directory: call MyObj.SaveTo("dir/test.txt")

Comment: Sure. I might use ".\dir\test.txt", though, but it's the same either way.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I will try them out